# How to prevent mui datatables render when set states in onRowSelectionChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatable, jsx, mui-datatable

I'm currently working on React js project with `"mui-datatables": "^4.2.2"`.

I have a list of data divided on pages with the possibility of selecting an item through a checkbox :

[image]

My problem :

when I select an item in the second page, the component rerender and automatically back to the first page.

I think the problem is a set state inside onRowSelectionChange :

```
  const options = {
    filter: false,
    onRowClick: (rowData, rowMeta) => {
      console.log("--rowData --");
      console.log(rowData);
      console.log("--rowMeta --");
      console.log(rowMeta);
    },
    onRowSelectionChange: (
      currentRowsSelected,
      allRowsSelected,
      rowsSelected
    ) => {
      let items = [];
      allRowsSelected.forEach((row) => {
        items.push(data[row.dataIndex]);
      });
      setSelectedRows(items);
    },
```

How can i fix this problem  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should store page number in the state as well say for example
`curPage:1`
when page change you should update the curPage as well,now you can use this inside the options props you pass to mui-datatable.like this

```
const options = {
page:this.state.curPage,//incase its class component
onChangePage:(page)=>{
 this.setState({curPage:page});//assuming its a class component
},
filter: false,
onRowClick: (rowData, rowMeta) => {
  console.log("--rowData --");
  console.log(rowData);
  console.log("--rowMeta --");
  console.log(rowMeta);
},
onRowSelectionChange: (
  currentRowsSelected,
  allRowsSelected,
  rowsSelected
) => {
  let items = [];
  allRowsSelected.forEach((row) => {
    items.push(data[row.dataIndex]);
  });
  setSelectedRows(items);
},
```

hope this will help

Comment: thanks to you answer I was able to think of "page" params,  i set page: 0 inside datatables options,